# regex to match a suffix in a given string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a function which is supposed to validate a string to not contain the below prefix
I want to match every word with

```
                        __test_timestamp__itemname
```

some examples are as follows

```
                       __test_1349333576093__cellphone_modelc1
                       __test_1349333576090__macbook_model_12
```

```
public boolean isvalid(String Name){
  /*pattern match to check for suffix and return true if string starts with 
    __test_timestamp_
 */
}
```

The person name in this string can vary and so will the timestamp which is in milliseconds , however the timestamp is 13 characters in length and consists of digits , the itemname  can contain numbers and underscore

How do I write a function to match this pattern ? Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiarized with java but the regex is something like this:

```
^__test_[0-9]{13}__[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

**^**: for start string

**[0-9]{13}**: 13 numbers

**[A-Za-z0-9_]+**: 1 or more Mayus/minus chars, numbers and _

**$**: for end string

https://regex101.com/r/oWBfes/2

Edit: If you need more flexibility for the timestamp, you can set min and max like this:

**{11,13}**

```
^__test_[0-9]{11,13}__[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

Edit: add 100 max length:

```
(?=^.{0,100}$)(^__test_[0-9]{11,13}__[A-Za-z0-9_]+$)
```

Edit: to group last occurrence:

```
(?=^.{0,100}$)^__test_[0-9]{11,13}__([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$/
```

To catch what you want, group it with ()

Comment: How do I use this to restrict the total length to 100 characters?

Comment: @dojacat edited the response, if you like it, check the "V" to mark as resolved

Comment: @ZiTAL if i had a string __test_1628234740938_product1 , how do i use the matcher to exclude __test_1628234740938_ and give me only product1

Answer (score 1):

You may use `String#matches` as follows:

```java
public boolean isvalid(String name) {
    return name.matches("__test_\\d+__\\S+");
}
```

Note that we don't assign any fixed width to the timestamp, because perhaps you have some earlier data whose timestamps could be less than 13 digits wide.

Comment: thank you for your reply . Since the time stamp is in milliseconds produced by System. currentTimeMillis()  , wont this always be 13 digits ?

Comment: Presumably this is some kind of UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.  A date from 1972 would therefore be only 11 digits, not 13.  You may want to keep things flexible for this reason.